# Running multiple threads from within a unit test

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, junit

Below is a unit test which uses ScheduledExecutorService to execute a scheduled runnable every second :

```
   import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ConcurrentRequestSimulator {

    private static final int NUMBER_REQUESTS = 4;

    @Test
    public void testGetToDoList() {

        try {
            ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RequestThreadInvoker(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private final class RequestThreadInvoker implements Runnable {

        public void run() {

            ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            for (int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_REQUESTS; i++) {
                es.execute(new RequestThread());
            }
            es.shutdown();

            while (!es.isTerminated()) {

            }

        }
    }

    private final class RequestThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("in RequestThread");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The line  `System.out.println("in RequestThread");` in `RequestThread` does not appear to be invoked as no output is displayed to console.
I think the issue is that since the test runs to completion, it causes the `scheduler` to stop scheduling? Can the test be updated so that `scheduler` is not terminated and `RequestThreadInvoker` is invoked repeatedly once per second ?

In `RequestThreadInvoker` I create a new instance of `ExecutorService`. Could this be causing the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Thread.sleep(99000);` to end of test causes test to wait 99 seconds which is enough time for test to run.